# Blazor ApexCharts: Using a list for Items?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, apexcharts

I am trying to display multiple Line charts automatically with a list of items with class "DataTime".

However, this error was returned:

`cannot convert from 'Dashboard.Pages.CompApexLine.DataItem' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Dashboard.Pages.CompApexLine.DataItem>'`

**View**

```
<ApexChart TItem="DataItem" Title="Measurement(mm)" XAxisType="XAxisType.Numeric">
    <ApexPointSeries    TItem="DataItem"
                                Items=@datas[i]
                                Name="Measurement"
                                SeriesType="SeriesType.Line"
                                XValue="@(e=>e.date)"
                                YValue="@(e=>e.value)" 
                                OrderBy="e=>e.X"
                                
            />
</ApexChart>
```

Are we not allowed to use List or Enumerable on ApexCharts for `Items`?

If so, do have have to declare a single class object specifically for each chart?

This may not achieve the "automatically" perspective.

Thanks!